# Android Native Preview diffrent with Real preview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio-3.0

I'm doing a homework task.
I already tried with relative or liner, event constraint layout
but preview is always different from the real preview in my phone.
My phone is Xiaomi Redmi Note 5a (55 inch, 1280 x 720 pixel)

[My device](https://prnt.sc/nbpr7t)

[Android Studio preview](https://prnt.sc/nbpr2a)

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Register"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="25dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_header" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="27dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@drawable/ic_header_back"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="15dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Register"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="55dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="16dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_width="328dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#808284"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Username"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:text=""
    android:textColorHint="#808284"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="72dp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText10"
    android:layout_width="330dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:backgroundTint="#808284"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Home Address"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:text=""
    android:textColorHint="#808284"
    android:textSize="10dp"
    android:typeface="normal"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="15dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="395dp" />
```

full code : https://pastebin.com/U9YdKK1m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You see this layout differently because you are using fixed size on your views, and different phones got different screen size - so using fixed size will make your layout non-responsive to all devices.

If you want to use constraintLayot you can simply use [chains](https://constraintlayout.com/basics/create_chains.html) to order your views vertically:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_width="27dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/textView3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.571" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
        android:text="Register"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText3"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#808284"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Username"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text=""
        android:textColorHint="#808284"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText10"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText10"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#808284"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Home Address"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text=""
        android:textColorHint="#808284"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/editText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText3" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:backgroundTint="#808284"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Home Address"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:text=""
        android:textColorHint="#808284"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:typeface="normal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/radioButton2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText10" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/radioButton2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/radioButton2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/radioButton2" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="RadioButton"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/guideline4"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/radioButton"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.5"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.Guideline
        android:id="@+id/guideline4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

It will look like this :

[image]

Comment: If that was helpful please accept the answer so it can help others